# Create shingles from two vectors

Tags: r

I'd like to classify the values of a data frame according to two columns. Let's say, I've got the following data frame:

```
my.df <- data.frame(a=c(1:20), b=c(61:80))
```

And now I want to subdivide it into 8 areas by dividing the 2D-scatterplot into 4 equal parts and then overlaying a rectangle in the middle that would consist of a quarter of each of the 4 parts. So far I've been using the following tedious way:

```
ar <- range(my.df$a)
br <- range(my.df$b)

aint <- seq(ar[1], ar[2], by=(ar[2]-ar[1])/4)
bint <- seq(br[1], br[2], by=(br[2]-br[1])/4)

my.df$z <- NA
my.df[which(my.df$a < aint[3] & my.df$b < bint[3]),"z"] <- 1
my.df[which(my.df$a < aint[3] & my.df$b >= bint[3]),"z"] <- 2
...
my.df[which(my.df$z == 1 & my.df$a >= aint[2] & my.df$b >= bint[2]),"z"] <- 5
...
```

I am sure there must be a way to do it in a neater and more general way, i.e. by writing a general function, but I am struggling to write one myself.

Also, I was surprised to see that after all of this, the class of the column `z` is automatically set to `shingle`. Why that? How does `R` "know" that this is a `shingle`?

Comment: You must have some unnamed package loaded  or  have attached some dataframe or... something. The class of "z' is "numeric".

Comment: @DWin I guess it's `lattice` or `latticeExtra`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach it by cutting it into 16 groups first (x and y into 4 groups independently) and then combining them back together into fewer groups.

```
my.df$a.q <- cut(my.df$a, breaks=4, labels=1:4)
my.df$b.q <- cut(my.df$b, breaks=4, labels=1:4)
my.df$a.b.q <- paste(my.df$a.q, my.df$b.q, sep=".")
my.df$z <- c("1.1"=1, "1.2"=1, "1.3"=2, "1.4"=2, 
             "2.1"=1, "2.2"=3, "2.3"=4, "2.4"=2,
             "3.1"=5, "3.2"=6, "3.3"=7, "3.4"=8,
             "4.1"=5, "4.2"=5, "4.3"=8, "4.4"=8)[my.df$a.b.q]
```

This seems reasonable

```
plot(my.df$a, my.df$b, col=my.df$z)
```

[image]

With some data with more coverage:

```
set.seed(1234)
my.df <- data.frame(a=runif(1000, 1, 20), b=runif(1000, 61, 80))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any idea how the creation of `z` can be done in a more general way, e.g. if I would want to subdivide the axes in more than four parts each? The more subdivisions, the more cumbersome it becomes to assign the "cluster". Also, I've tried to use `col=my.df$a.b.q` for plotting so that 16 populations get coloured, but only 4 populations (subdivided according to `a`) got coloured although `length(unique(my.df$a.b.q))` is 16. Why aren't the colours assigned according to unique entries in `a.b.q`?

Comment: Thanks Brian! I actually like your approach with cutting and vector indexing very much.